# Merge multiple .htaccess rewrite rules into single line?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We're launching a new site and l need to redirect several old URLs. In my .htaccess i have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Countries/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^England/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Dependent_Areas/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Ireland/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Northern_Ireland/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Scotland/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$
RewriteRule ^Wales/(.*) "/local/" [R=301,QSA,L,NC]
```

Which works, but l was curious what a cleaner way to do so is?
Baiscally l just need to redirect:

```
^Countries/(.*)
^Dependent_Areas/(.*)
^England/(.*)
^Ireland/(.*)
^Northern_Ireland/(.*)
^Scotland/(.*)
^Wales/(.*)
```

All to their new location which is /local/ - this redirect happens on 2 different domains

The code I have works, but l would like to merge this all into one rules, and l'm not quite sure how that is done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your condition looks same for all domains, you could make a combine rule like as follows. Also you need not to create capturing groups as we are NOT using them later in rules, so I have changed it to `(?:.......)` non-capturing group here.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:Countries|England|Dependent_Areas|Ireland|Northern_Ireland|Scotland|Wakes)/.*$ /local/ [R=301,QSA,L,NC]
```

Few suggestions for improvement: Following could be used also apart from above mentioned details.

- Add `NC` flag in your first condition to make it case insensitive match.
- In case you want to catch www(optional) in hostname change your current cond part to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain1\.com|domain2\.com)$ [NC]`.